# Multiple Angle Identity with $\sin(11x)$

Tags: trigonometry

I have a problem that I cannot seem to solve. I need to prove the following identity,

$$\sin(11x) = 2\sin(8x)\cos(3x)-\sin(5x)$$

I do not understand how to go about this problem, as clearly expanding each term using compound and double angle formulas would be inefficient and take up a lot of space. I feel like there must be a shortcut to take. I have a test tomorrow and this is one of the practice questions. Therefore, I would immensely appreciate any help right now!

Comment: $11=3+8$ and $8=3+5$. Try compound angle formulas for this, and maybe you'll get it

Comment: ^ Those formulas are also known as Angle-Sum Formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main formula (you either know it or you don't - meaning either it has been taught in class or your book, or if not then it's an unfair problem) is this:

$\sin A + \sin B = 2 \sin \frac {A+B} 2 \cos \frac {A-B} 2$.

Have you seen this before? And if so, can you use it now?

Comment: But it gives a very strong hint of how to do the problem...So to the OP: Bring over that sin5x term to the left and this problem is easy...

Answer (score 1):

By [Werner Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html),  $$2\sin8x\cos3x=\sin(8x+3x)+\sin(8x-3x)$$

Now rearrange

OR

by [Prosthaphaeresis](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) Formula,  $$\sin11x+\sin5x=2\sin\dfrac{11x+5x}2\cos\dfrac{11x-5x}2=?$$